# Redux Subscribe with compose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a fairly specific implementation questions. I am working on a project and they have already configured their Redux Store and added in a middleware for what the project would need. I am trying to persist my data to local storage but normally I go through and when I create a store I add subscribe and then add the following code.

```
const saveToLocalStorage = state => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const loadFromLocalStorage = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return undefined;
  }
};

const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  persistedState,
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));
```

I am trying to implement something similar to the following but also add it and change as few things as possible to the following code which was from the boilerplate when configuring the project.

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

I am not that familiar with compose and adding in additional middleware so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a store with middle ware you can do this like

```
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            library: libraryReducer,
            filters: filterReducer,
            auth: authReducer
        }),
        composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
    return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

Store means the initial empty state of some default state for your web app. And if you want to populate your store with data then you should use actions and reducer to store all your data because they are in existence for that purpose only.